# How to recover deleted Stack Overflow posts

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I accidentally deleted a post on Stack Overflow. Is there a way to recovered deleted Stack Overflow posts?

I have checked the information available under the Stack Overflow profile, and the deleted item was not found there.

Comment: When did you delete it? Do you have a link in your browser history?

Comment: Was it a question or an answer? When (approximately) did you originally post it.

Comment: You can see your deleted questions and answers (I believe posted within the last 60 days?) in your profile by hitting Questions > 'deleted recent questions' at the bottom, and by Answers > 'deleted recent answers'

Comment: This will lead you to your [deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/10282307) and [deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/10282307)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the recently deleted question and answer you can

- Open the activity tab.
- Click on the questions tab or answers tab
- Scroll to the bottom and you can see deleted recent question or answers as per the tab

[image]

Moderators can see your deleted posts. Rob has provided the [deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/10282307) and 
[deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/10282307)